# Url modify in angular

Tags: url, angular6

I have angular application(angular 6) which implemented keycloakAuthentication ,if user is not authenticated angular application redirect user to this service page(third party), when user successfully authenticated he will redirect to our angular website .

Now i am facing issue with http protocol if user type **http://portal.cloud.com** they will redirect to keycloakAuthentication  page but redirect url(http://portal.cloud.com) is invalid because it is authenticating only   https url ,how i can modify url in this case means if user type   **http://portal.cloud.com**  application will automatically convert it into **https://portal.cloud.com**  and send it to keycloakAuthentication  page.
I tried some solution like implemented authguard as below:

```
import {Injectable, isDevMode} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class IsSecureGuard implements CanActivate {

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if ((isDevMode()) && (location.protocol !== 'https:')) {
      location.href = 'https:' + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

but it is not working as expected please suggests some solution to modify url on load.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your implementation by resolving the redirect to HTTPS before the user reaches your application, by setting up NGINX to do this for example:

See here how to: https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom